# Calculating taxable income and tax rate using asp.net, html and c#

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

My goal here is to compute the federal income tax based on the taxable income using asp.net, c# and html. Below is what I've coded so far. Summary: The user inputs annual income and number of dependents via text boxes. There is a $1000 deduction for every dependent. Taxable income = annual income – (number of dependents * 1000). I need to multiply the taxable income with the tax rate.

I am having difficulties calculating this value of taxable income, and still need to code the calculate button to do it's job.

```
Taxable Income Range and Tax Rate:
>450000 -- 39.6%.
>378000 and <=450000 -- 33%.
>192000 and <=378000 -- 28%.
>71000 and <=192000 -- 25%.
>15000 and <=71000 -- 15%.
<=15000 -- 10%.

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Form1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Form1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">
           Enter your name here: <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br /><br />
           Annual Income: <asp:TextBox ID="income" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br /><br />
           Number of dependents: <asp:TextBox ID="dependents" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="calculate" runat="server" Text="Calculate Tax" OnClick="calculate_Click" />
    <br /><br />        
          Total Tax: <asp:TextBox ID="total" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the .cs, I also need to edit the _rates second to represent the table above of taxable income and tax rate.

```
namespace WebApplication1 {
}
public class IncomeTaxCalculator
{
protected List<KeyValuePair<double, int>> _rates = null;
protected IncomeTaxCalculator()
{
    // Load from database.
    _rates = new List<KeyValuePair<double, int>>();
    _rates.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, int>(.10, 15000));
    _rates.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, int>(.15, 15000));
    _rates.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, int>(.25, 71000));
    _rates.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, int>(.28, 192000));
    _rates.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, int>(.33, 378000));
    _rates.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, int>(.396, 450000));
}
public double Single(int income)
{
    double tax = 0;
    for (int i = _rates.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (income > _rates[i].Value)
        {
            tax += (income - _rates[i].Value) * _rates[i].Key;
            income = _rates[i].Value;
        }
    }
    return tax;
}
// Singletone
protected static IncomeTaxCalculator _instance = null;
public static IncomeTaxCalculator Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new IncomeTaxCalculator();
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}
}
public partial class Form1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(IncomeTaxCalculator.Instance.Single(40000).ToString("C"));
    }
    protected void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form1 doesn't have an `Instance`. You might want to:

```
Response.Write(IncomeTaxCalculator.Instance.Single(40000).ToString("C"));
```

Comment: what is the next move here?

Comment: you should really ask that as a second question, and mark my response as the answer (if it solves your first issue). I will say, however, that it looks like you are trying to use a single value (int) when you need to represent a range (int min and int max). I would either just keep the data in the database and query it, or create another class to store rate, min, and max.